# What is this weird function parameter?

Tags: c++

today I came across this weird code:

```cpp
auto rovoid_iterator
    (
        Construct ROII* const at,
        auto(ROII&)(auto(*)(Str&&)noexcept->void) ->void //WTF??
    ) -> void;
```

What the hell is this weird second parameter??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lookup "trailing return type in C++".

Comment: I think the technical term for that kind of parameter is "abomination".

Comment: I know these trailing return types but what is this parameter? A pointer a reference and to what?

Comment: it looks to me like an argument that wants a function which has one argument whose type is itself a pointer to a function which in turn takes an `Str&&` as argument and they all return `void`. Or I may be confused.

Comment: What is `ROII`? And how can something be declared `Construct ROII`?

Comment: But i tought function pointers are like void(*func)() why is there the ampersand & in the first and this weird ROII and a * pointer in the second??!!! Im so confused!

Comment: This is not C++ code.  `Construct ROII* const at` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: Wait im going to look what ROII is

Comment: It is for sure it compiles with c++ 17 and msvc

Comment: If you write a line of code, and the cost of someone else understanding that code is measurable in man-hours, I think you need a very strong justification to not rewrite that line.

Comment: This is ROII - nothing: //Mark internal RO_VOID_ITERATOR pointer handle
#define ROII - Its used to mark something

Comment: Yes its just an empty macro wich should mark something for the user

Comment: @Noel2019 Then it is probably a tag or attribute used by a compiler or code generation/analysis tool in your build chain. For the purpose of understanding the line, you can simply pretend it is not present.

Comment: Im going to call the dev who wrote this wait...

Comment: Okay but when its not present the parameter is still weird

Comment: Alright he explained it ill write an answer

Comment: @Noel2019 "It is for sure it compiles with c++ 17 and msvc" - Just because something compiles does *not* always mean it is *valid*. "It compiles" is a *very low* bar and in no way guarantees correctness.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you made my day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, let's deconstruct this abomination.

First, there's a inner type:

```
auto(*)(Str&&) noexcept -> void
```

This is a pointer to function taking a `Str` rvalue-reference as parameter. It's also a noexcept function.

Let's call that `S`

```
using S = auto(*)(Str&&) noexcept -> void;
```

Then the outer part of the parameter can be subtitued like that:

```
auto(ROII&)(S) -> void
```

As you stated in the comments, `ROII` is an empty macro. So in the end it reads like that:

```
auto(&)(S) -> void
```

That code appear to be a parameter which would be a reference to function that take a `S` which is and return `void`.

Comment: Interesting to note that the parameter does not appear to have any sort of name. Maybe it has one in the definition.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not so surprising. This is a function declaration, parameters don't need names there.

Comment: Ninja'd by my edit. But note that `at` has a name, so it was decided that the first argument deserved a name in the declaration but not the second.

Comment: Thank you ;) The same as the author said

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux nice catch. This is indeed suspicious

Comment: @Noel2019 I would strongly consider making an alias for the `S` function type. That would make it much more easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I asked the dev who wrote this:

```
auto(ROII&)(auto(*)(Str&&)noexcept->void) ->void
```

Is a reference to a function which takes a function pointer as argument.
This function pointer is a pointer because its okay to pass nullptr if you dont need it,
but the first function must be passed thats why it is a reference. The second pointer is a pointer to a function wich is noexcept and takes a rvalue reference to a string as paremeter. ROII marks game ready functions.

Comment: Could you ask him... why? Why in the name of all that is good, would he feel the need to do this?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez It's the modern evolution of the [three star programmer](http://don.fed.wiki.org/view/three-star-programmer). Maybe the three lambda programmer or something.

Comment: I will ask him ;) wait and what does three star programmer mean? Oh didnt see the link never mind

Comment: A "three star programmer" is a programmer who writes unnecessarily complicated code, partly because they want to show off how smart they are. Generally speaking, it's frowned upon. The name comes from people who'd use pointers to pointers to pointers (like `int***`, which has three stars after the `int`).

Comment: To be honest, that style of programming makes him a liability to his team. Complicated code is more difficult to maintain; harder to debug; harder to modify to fit the needs of future projects; and it oftentimes ends up being slower in the long run.

Comment: Luckily hes only doing this in the core engine wich only he is writing. To give him credit his api layer for us gameplay programmers is pretty, clean and modern :D Thanks for your help have a nice day :)

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I once saw code that had 5 stars and it was necessary.. for being FEMA  model written in  VS6.0 code (Studio was abomination of C++ incompleteness) .. but my boss still doesn't believe me that I'm afraid of it. To question why to use trailing return types? To make code look similar to code where it is necessary (if return type is dependent on something else). It kinda helps resolving merging or  conflicts